# Laravel 8: How can I make an implicitly model bound route parameter optional instead of throwing 404?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-8

I've tried to combine the Laravel docs on [implicit binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding) and [optional parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-optional-parameters) and have the following code.

routes file:

```php
Route::get('go/{example?}', [ExampleController::class, 'click'])->name('example');
```

And in the controller:

```php
public function click(Example $example = null)
{
    // Execution never reaches here
}
```

Execution never reaches the controller unless there is an Example with the correct slug, as it throws a 404. I want to check if `$example` is null in the controller and use custom logic there. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```php
Route::get('go/{example?}', [ExampleController::class, 'click'])->name('example');
```

```php
public function click($example)
{
    if($example != null){
        $example = Example::findOrfail($example);
    }

    
}
```

in model binding it will automatically run `findOrfail` to that model so don't you that so you will have control over it then you can manage

Comment: This works. I was hoping to keep the type hint and route model binding. You're saying there's no way to configure Laravel to find instead of findOrFail?

Comment: @Menasheh yes because by default Laravel is using   `findOrFail` in model binding

Comment: @Menasheh yes you can override the findOrFail by explicitly declaring your own binding of a model, see this link: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-resolution-logic

Answer (score 0):

the @ettdro answer is perfect (and all credit is to him), but i think  an answer with actual code would be useful:

routes:

```
Route::get('go/{example?}', [ExampleController::class, 'click'])->name('example');
```

controller:

```
public function click(Example $example)
{
    // Stuff
}
```

Model of Example:

```
 /**
 * Retrieve the model for a bound value.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @param  string|null  $field
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
 */
public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null)
{
    $result=$this->where('id', $value)->first();
    return ($result)?$result:new Example();
}
```

You should obtain in the controller always a valid object, empty or not.

Had the same problem, and i'm happy with this solution.

Answer (score -1):

To do that, you need use 'id' as your primary key in database and model,

if you are using another name for your pimary key, then you need to define it at your route:

```
Route::get('go/{example:number?}', [...]);
```

Comment: How would that help?